# How to setup seemly circular but not actually circular dependencies in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Below is the scenario :

Pipeline A triggered by Tumbling Window Trigger A - Runs Every Hour.

Pipeline B triggered by Tumbling Windows Trigger B - Runs Every Week.

I want A to run only after :

a. last run of A is successful. (self dependency - doable).

b. last run of B is successful.  ( This is also doable but can get into circular dependency because of point b in below lines)

I want B to run only after :

a. last run of B is successful. ( self dependency - doable)

b. last run of A is successful. ( This gets into circular dependency issue when we publish and later when it generates ARM templates)

Here A is having frequency of 1 hour and B is having frequency of 1 week.

consider B is to next execute on 9th Feb 12:00 AM for window of 2nd Feb - 9th Feb.

Also, A is about to execute on 9th Feb 12:00 Am for window of 8th Feb 11:00 PM - 12:00 PM.

In this case both runs will collide at 9th Feb 12:00 AM. Can we setup dependency so that it does not collide.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi, i am yet to try this approach. But i guess, an idea that i can use from below is , to setup dependency via Execute pipeline dependency and make a facade pipeline rather than doing similar thing via triggers, to avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Yes,i agree that trigger is needed.Any concern about your test,pls let me know.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide below ideas for your reference:

1.Firstly,put the pipelines into [Execute Pipeline Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity) because you may have to do some steps before and after execution of A and B pipelines.

2.Secondly,since the pipelines have to be executed with some conditions,i think you could persist the results of A and B pipelines execution anyway.For example,after executing pipeline,use an [Azure Function Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) or [Web Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) to send the result of pipeline into some residences. The aim is logging the latest execute result of A and B.

3.Finally,before the execution of A and B pipelines,you could use an [Until Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity) to evaluate whether the pipeline could be executed.